# How to filter state abbreviations from strings

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have XML where the /forms/form/@number can be in almost any format (any combination of letters, numbers and single spaces).  Occasionally there will be @number values which are the same form...but are state specific.  When this happens the last 3 characters will be a single space followed by the state abbreviation.  So the last two characters are the state abbreviation...if it is present at all.  I need to be able to select these 'identical' forms for processing.

XSLT 2.0 is fine.  I'm thinking the solution would involve keys or perhaps 2.0 grouping methods but I am at a loss.  NOTE:  I still need to iterate over the forms that do not have state-specific matches in the same loop...it is just that I have to do something special for the ones that multiple states.  Of course I don't have control over the XML.

```
<forms>
<!-- THESE 3 WOULD MATCH -->
<form number="ABC 12 45"/>
<form number="ABC 12 45 IL"/>
<form number="ABC 12 45 KY"/>
<!-- 2 OF 3 WOULD MATCH AS ZZ IS NOT A STATE -->
<form number="CGF 45"/>
<form number="CGF 45 ZZ"/>
<form number="CGF 45 IL"/>
<!-- THESE 3 WOULD MATCH -->
<form number="955EZ IL"/>
<form number="955EZ MN"/>
<form number="955EZ CA"/>
<!-- NO MATCHES -->
<form number="25 AB 4"/>
<form number="SR HL DR"/>
</forms>
```

Comment: Are the related forms always together in the file?

Comment: They are all within the same nodeset but not always adjacent to each other. Meaning they are not sorted when they come in.  They will all be under the 'forms' node though.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and easy (both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0) solution. :)

Comment: @johkar: If you are grouping by sequence except posible last two letters item, it's not clear why the three "CGF 45" starters can't be grouped together...

Comment: @johkar: I updated my answer and think it now fully solves your problem.

Comment: @johkar: Also added an XSLT 2.0 solution. :)

Comment: Alejandro: CGF 45 ZZ would not be considered the same form because the last two characters are not a state abbreviation code.  It was probably a bad example; I was trying to illustrate that I am not just looking at the last two characters blindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:template match=
  "form[substring(@number, string-length(@number) -2, 1)=' '
      and
       translate(substring(@number, string-length(@number)-1),
                 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                ) = ''
      and
       contains('|AL|AK|AZ|AR|...|WA|WI|WY|',
                concat('|',substring(@number, string-length(@number)-1),'|')
                )
       =
        ''
       ]">

<!-- Needed processing here -->

</xsl:template>
```

**XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:template match=
  "form[substring(@number, string-length(@number) -2, 1)=' '
      and
       substring(@number, string-length(@number)-1)
      =
       ('AL','AK','AZ','AR',...,'WA','WI','WY') 
       ]">

<!-- Needed processing here -->

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1 Good filter. This would be needed for the key value calculation. If the question gets fixed!

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks. He doesn't mention "grouping" at all. BTW, did you read the 2nd part of my post on Binary Search Tree in XPath 3.0?

Comment: Dimitre: Thanks, I can incorporate this now.